# Upload media to Dropbox

Tags: wordpress, dropbox

I want to know if there is any plugin that allow me to upload the media to a Dropbox location, instead of the traditional `wp-content/upload` folder?

P.S.: All the plugins that I find using Google concerns the backup to dropbox.

I'm looking for an equivalent of **tantan-s3-cloudfront** for dropbox instead of Amazon S3.

This is because my blog is hosted on Heroku, so I have to find a way to store media outside of Heroku.

Comment: you may need to use dropbox API for this - i am not sure even if you can do this. A custom modification will be good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Plugin:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/drop-in-dropbox/

But i assume if you want realtime file hosting and serving from dropbox, you may need to write your own plugin/module and integrate Dropbox API.

Comment: Indeed! Like __tantan-s3-cloudfront__, I'm looking for transparent/realtime file hosting with Dropbox. Strange that no-one created a "ready to use" plugin that integrates Dropbox into WordPress!!

Comment: As per my knowledge, there's no ready to use plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be the thing you re looking for but i didnt test it
http://wordpress.org/plugins/drop-in-dropbox/

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin, it has both dropins (Chooser & Saver): http://codecanyon.net/item/wp-dropbox-dropins-/6502105